# Enforcing inequality of lists?

Tags: list, prolog, constraints, eclipse-clp

For a given CSP I used a variety of viewpoints, one of which is a somewhat more exotic boolean model which uses a variable array of size `NxNxN`. Then I enforce unequality of various subarrays with this snippet :

```
(foreach(X, List1), 
 foreach(Y, List2), 
 foreach((X #\= Y), Constraints) 
 do true),
1 #=< sum(Constraints).
```

The performance of the model is bad, so I was curious to know more about what happens behind the scenes. Is this a proper way to ensure that two given lists are different? Do I understand it correctly that every constraint (`X #\= Y`) in the `Constraints` list needs to be instantiated before the sum is calculated, meaning that all the corresponding variables need to be instantiated too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint library `library(ic_global)` is indeed missing a constraint here; it should provide `lex_ne/2`, analogous to [lex_lt/2](https://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic_global/lex_lt-2.html).  This would have the same logical and operational behaviour as the code you have written, i.e. propagate when there is only a single variable left in its argument lists:

```
?- B#::0..1, lex_ne([1,0,1], [1,B,1]).
B = 1
```

For comparison, you can try the sound difference operator [~=/2](https://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/termcomp/TE-2.html) (called dif/2 in some Prologs). This is efficiently implemented, but it doesn't know about domains and will thererefore not propagate; it simply waits until both sides are instantiated and then fails or succeeds:

```
?- B#::0..1, [1,0,1] ~= [1,B,1].
B = B{[0, 1]}
There is 1 delayed goal.

?- B#::0..1, [1,0,1] ~= [1,B,1], B = 0.
No (0.00s cpu)
```

Whether this is overall faster will depend on your application.